# C++ thread constructor, using new(object) creates memory leaks

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory, memory-leaks

I have a program that has a class, A, that I want to run in a thread.  Really, it is that A is a worker and I am going to have some number of these that are running that I want to keep track of.  My problem is that my current way of doing this causes a memory leak when I check it with valgrind.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class A {
    public:
        double foobar;

        A() : foobar(0) { };
        A(double newfoo) : foobar(newfoo) { };
        void runA(double asap) {
            foobar = asap;
            std::cout << "foobar is now index: " << foobar << std::endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread> aThreads;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        aThreads.push_back(std::thread(&A::runA, new A(1), i));
    }

    for(auto& t : aThreads) {
        t.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So I know that the problem is the `new A(100)` call, and I am really not sure how to deal with this.  My actual program is much bigger, and so leaks a lot more memory, so I am wondering what I can do here.  I tried creating the object in the for loop, and then using `std::move()` to attempt to hand said object to the thread, but that failed miserably as well.  I know I have to pass in the memory address, and I know that I want the distinct objects separate as they will be doing different tasks.

How do you solve the problem of leaked memory in the case where you need to create a bunch of objects to run in their own separate threads?

Comment: Does each object need to be cleaned up as soon as the associated thread finishes, or is it OK to clean them all up after all the threads are done?

Comment: One option is, at end of `A::runA()`, do `delete this;`.  But only if `A` is always dynamically allocated... which you can enforce by making the destructor private.

Comment: It doesn't need to be cleaned up as soon as it's allocated, so I'm going with users answer below.  I've already cleaned up one of the problems, but I am leaking a crapload of indirect memory somewhere else in the threads themselves.  I think it's that valgrind is reporting the memory that the program itself used, so I need to check into that and why it's flagging it as bad.

Comment: Just pass the objects by value to the thread constructor: `aThreads.push_back(std::thread(&A::runA, A(1), i));`. You can't have leaks if you don't use `new`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save all pointers to allocated objects(in a vector, for example) and then call delete on them after your join threads.

Comment: This solved some of the problems, and should have been obvious to me.  Now valgrind is just telling me that I'm leaking a bunch indirectly, which is either me not tearing down properly at the end (which is better) involving all the threads, or the containers that I am using, which is also possible.

Comment: It actually wound up being a lot more complicated.  I did the delete on the threads, but I was still losing data to the std::map containers in each thread.  I realized that I needed to be able to keep track of them from the main thread, just passing around pointers, which then allowed me to delete them at the end.  No memory leaks!

Answer (score 4):

Make `A` callable directly, then pass it by value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

class A {
    public:
        double foobar;

        A() : foobar(0) { };
        A(double newfoo) : foobar(newfoo) { };
        void operator()(double asap) {
            foobar = asap;
            std::cout << "foobar is now index: " << foobar << std::endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::thread> aThreads;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        aThreads.push_back(std::thread(A(1), i));
    }

    for(auto& t : aThreads) {
        t.join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In my second implementation I am going with this, trying to optimize some things with the queue.